# Entity Framework 7 migrations - OnConfiguring bug

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was trying to add migrations to my EF7 project using package manager console,
but I found out that the package manager console need you to have 3 disturbing things:

1. Parameterless ctor (weird.. Yet not disturbing)
2. You have to override `OnConfiguring` method.... (why do I have to?)
3. You have to config your db connection in the `OnConfiguring` method!

Those three things take my pleasure to implement dependency injection and by that take the possibility to use in-memory Database (unit test).

(Those three point I stated above came from the package manager console exceptions I encountered them when I tried to `Add-Migration`)

Sorry for not dnxing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are two other options not mentioned.

1. Use a class named Startup to add your context to an IoC container.

   ```
   class Startup
   {
       void ConfigureServices(IServiceContainer services)
           => services
               .AddEntityFramework()
               .AddSqlServer()
               .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
                   options => options.UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
   }
   ```
2. Tell EF how to construct your context at design-time using IDbContextFactory.

   ```
   class MyDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
   {
       public MyDbContext Create()
       {
           // TODO: Construct your context
           return new MyDbContext();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: could use an updated example how to implement IDbContextFactory in rc2. I'm having trouble getting migrations to run with my ef code in a class library, changed to app as stated in the workaround notes but when I try to run dotnet ef ... it says no parameterless constructor found. I started trying to implement IDbContextFactory but now vs2015 hangs and becomes unresponsive but no error indicated, kill the process and open solution it hangs again immediately